# Get sorted output for os.walk()

Tags: python, os.walk

I have a piece of code which goes like this :

```
import os
for r,d,f in os.walk('/home/vibhor/Downloads'):
     print(r,len(f))
```

I need to have a sorted output on the number of files , which prints the output sorted on the basis of number of files present under a sub-directory , What changes should I do to the code .

Comment: Add an example of input and expected output please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep the data in some list, then sort it with the length as key. Then you can move on to do whatever you want with the sorted data.

In the example below, `data` contains pairs of directory and number of files, sorted.

```
data = [(r, len(f)) for r, d, f in os.walk('/home/vibhor/Downloads')]
data = sorted(data, key=lambda x: x[1])
```

Answer (score 2):

Define the key you want to use for sorting as follows:

```
print(sorted([(r, d, f) for r, d, f in os.walk('/home/vibhor/Downloads')], key=lambda x: len(x[2]), reversed=True))
```

`reversed=True` gives the answer in decreasing order.

Comment: OP claimed he needed only the dirnames and num of files. Why keep all the dirs and files in the list comprehension?

Comment: And which part of the OP got you to that conclusion? I only see him asking to order by the ammount of files inside a directory.